White boy growing up among African tribe
I'm looking for the name of a movie or 2-part miniseries with the following plot ingredients:

white boy is found by an African tribe (with red clothes) (pretty sure)
I'm uncertain whether the mother was killed or the boy was abandoned as a kid
boy grows up but during some fight with local kids is left for dead on the savannah (pretty sure)
boy kills leopard and wears skin (pretty sure)
boy is adopted by another tribe (with blue clothes)
there is a scene were the boy has to grab a snake from a basket as an acceptance test by the new tribe (pretty sure)
new tribe and old tribe go to war (somewhat sure)

I saw this movie in the early 80s (definitely pre-1986) on Dutch TV, but I'm guessing it could have been made as early as the early 70s. Pretty sure it was not Dutch language, though I can't remember any dialogue. My guess is that it's a South African production.
After doing some more research, it seems that the movie I'm looking for is a cross between Shaka Zulu (which I didn't see until many years after it came out), The John Ross Story: An African Adventure (came out in 1987, never seen, 13-part series) and Sheena (which I haven't seen).

Sounds like the Italian\German mini-series Orzowei, il figlio della savana (Orzowei,  Son of the Savannah) from 1977 based on the book Orzowei from 1955 about a white boy abandoned in a South African jungle and adopted by a Swazi tribe. You can see the boy killing a cheetah and then wearing its skin (as well as the red tribal clothes) here:




The plot is pretty distinct (and your description was very thorough), so it wasn't hard. Glad you found it!

I meant: did you search your own memory, or did you use some magic search terms in IMDB/wiki/google?

Google. Like you, I was familiar with similar plots, but I don't think I saw this mini-series before.
